# Yearless Ruby dates?

Tags: ruby, datetime, date

Is there a way to represent dates like 12/25 without year information? I'm thinking of just using an array of `[month, year]` unless there is a better way.

Comment: I saw you accepted using strftime as the best answer. The site http://www.foragoodstrtime.com is an easy way to generate the date formatting strings.

Comment: Mike, you had a typo on the site URL.  It should be foragoodstrftime.com  I had never seen that site before, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* use the Date class and hard set the year to a leap year (so that you could represent 2/29 if you wanted). This would be convenient if you needed to perform 'distance' calculations between two dates (assuming that you didn't need to wrap across year boundaries and that you didn't care about the off-by-one day answers you'd get when crossing 2/29 incorrectly for some years).

It might also be convenient because you could use `#strftime` to display the date as (for example) "Mar-3" if you wanted.

Depending on the usage, though, I think I would probably represent them explicitly, either in a paired array or something like `YearlessDate = Struct.new(:month,:day)`. That way you're not tempted to make mistakes like those mentioned above.

However, I've never had a date that wasn't actually associated with a year. Assuming this is the case for you, then @SeanHill's answer is best: keep the year info but don't display it to the user when it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the strftime function from the Time class.

```
time = Time.now
time.strftime("%m/%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Phrogz answer makes perfect sense, it has a downside:

```
YearlessDate = Struct.new(:month,:day)
yearless_date = YearlessDate.new(5, 8)
```

This interface is prone to `MM, DD` versus `DD, MM` confusion.

You might want to use `Date` instead and consider the year 0 as "yearless date" (provided you're not a historian dealing with real dates around bc/ad of course).

The year 0 is a leap year and therefore accommodates every possible day/month duple:

```
Date.parse("0000-02-29").leap?   #=> true
```

If you want to make this convention air tight, just define your own class around it, here's a minimalistic example:

```
class YearlessDate < Date
  private :year
end
```

Answer (score -2):

The most "correct" way to represent a date without a year is as a Fixnum between 001 and 365. You can do comparisons on them without having to turn it into a date, and can easily create a date for a given year as needed using Date.ordinal

Comment: But what if it's a leap year and your date is February 29th